# Подгрузка аяксом категории выбранного типа в rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть посты, типы постов и категории типов. Задача - в `rails_admin`, при создании поста, сначала выбирать тип, потом категорию выбранного типа (подгрузка аяксом). Может кто сталкивался с этим? Не хочется свою админку писать только из-за этого..

Comment: Возможно, гугление по фразе active_admin nested forms чуть-чуть поможет. Хотя, что-то мне подсказывает, что придется как минимум писать свой партиал для active_admin. Сам недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой, но решил просто изменением схемы базы данных и ухода от такой структуры :)

Comment: active_admin гибче, но речь о rails_admin :) заказчик диктует